# Using case in loop to score and rank

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to score and rank X number of people based on several criterion.  Each row represents 1 person and they are ranked on several columns of criteria with set answers (i.e. level of education: AS, BS, MS, PhD... etc.).  I want to translate these answers into a score (1-5) using the CASE function.  (i.e. case1 education = BS, education_score = 2) and do that for each category.  Then i will add up all the scores (education_score + experience_score + ... etc.) and rank them based on that score.  I am unsure how to use a loop from 1 to i for all people on the sheet so that no matter how many people are entered it covers all of them.  I am also unsure how to use the CASE function properly to set the _score variables to the correct value based on the input for that criterion.  I hope that make sense!

Comment: It *sort of* makes sense.  Can you share an example of your data so we can see how it's laid out?  Also, ***Welcome to [so]!***  Be sure to check out the [tour], as well as [ask].  If you're having an issue with something _specific_, please [edit] your questions to provide more information and examples (like described in here: [mcve]) and share what you've tried & where you've looked so far. The goal is to make it as easy as possible for others to help you. :)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/33sEf

Thats an example of the setup altough there will be a lot more people and more will get added overtime, and there are more categories.  So i want it to go through each person and then through each column for that person and if they have a BS it would be a 2 and if they have medium experience its a 3 and so on for each column. Then at the end I would add up the total column score and it would paste that in the very last column for that person.  Then i will use RANK.EQ() to rank each person based on their score

Comment: Have you tried to make a code so far, and if so please add it to your question so we can se what you have or havn't done yet.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is just to one way of doing what you want.. Scores need to be ajusted to what you want. Also the range and sheet name needs to be ajusted to your sheet.

[Sheet Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9OKu.jpg)

Im using a [Ucase](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ucase-function-0c9b8b77-dd3b-46ec-ac46-b034fef54224) when i loop the scoreboard so it don't matter if you input `High, high, HIGH, higH` ect. it get's converterd to `HIGH` in the code so you always match the criteria

You can add more rows and columns, and the code will automaticly ajust the loops, just make sure that the last column is `Score`, unless you change the loops.

```
Private Sub Score()
    '***********************
    ' Declare variables
    '***********************
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim iPersons As Integer
    Dim iScore As Integer
    Dim iScoreBoard As Integer

    '***********************
    ' Initialize variables
    '***********************
    Set ws = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<--- Change to your sheet name 
    iScore = 0
    '***********************
    ' Main
    '***********************
    For iPersons = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        For iScoreBoard = 2 To ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1
            Select Case UCase(ws.Cells(iPersons, iScoreBoard).Value)
                'Degrees
                Case "AS"
                    iScore = iScore + 1
                Case "BS"
                    iScore = iScore + 2
                Case "MS"
                    iScore = iScore + 3
                Case "PHD"
                    iScore = iScore + 4
                'Experience
                Case "LOW"
                    iScore = iScore + 1
                Case "MEDIUM"
                    iScore = iScore + 2
                Case "HIGH"
                    iScore = iScore + 3
                Case "EXTREME"
                'Certified
                Case "N"
                    iScore = iScore + 1
                Case "Y"
                    iScore = iScore + 2
            End Select
            ws.Cells(iPersons, ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Value = iScore
        Next iScoreBoard
    iScore = 0
    Next iPersons
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew thats what i needed to do but I just started out so I was unsure how to properly translate my thoughts into code.